# meteor updating template from event

Tags: javascript, templates, meteor

I've just started using Meteor and I really like it, but I think I'm doing something wrong in handling templates and events which doesn't feel very reactive.

In my event I have something like

```
Template.login.event({
   'submit form': function(e, t){
      var password = t.find('#password').value;
      if (password.length < 5) return t.find('#error').innerHTML = 'password too short';

    // a bunch more stuff to handle success cases -- not important for this example
   }
});
```

In my template, I have

```
<template name="login">
  <span id="error"></span>
  <form>
    <input name="email" type="email" />
    <input name="password" type="password" id="password" />
  <form>
</template>
```

I'm thinking I should be somehow able to say something like
`t.data.error = 'password too short`  so I'm updating the data in the template, and use `<span id="error">{{error}}</span>` instead of updating the html directly, but I can't seem to find how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need a reactive variable to glue the helpers/events together. The easiest way is using `Session`, though I don't like it personally, due to its global scope

```
Template.login.event({
   'submit form': function(e, t){
      e.preventDefault(); // should stop the form submission, check the condition and then continue with the submission if validation is correct
      var password = t.find('#password').value;
      if (password.length < 5) Session.set('error', "password too short");
   }
});

Template.login.helpers({
    isFormInValid: function(){
        return Session.get('error') != null;
    },
    errorMsg: function() {
        return Session.get('error');
    }
}); 

{{#if isFormInValid}}
<span id="error">{{errorMsg}}</span>
{{/if}}
```

Comment: Just replace the `Session` with a `ReactiveVar` created in `onCreated`. Almost as easy as using `Session`. :)

Comment: yup. i aware of `ReativeVar`. Actually, i never used `Session` in all the projects I worked with ;)